# Sumar propiedad númerica de objetos y clasificarlos por mes

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Tengo un arreglo de esta forma:

```
meses = 
[
    {
        "name": "Marzo",
        "value": 49
    },
    {
        "name": "Marzo",
        "value": 64
    },
    {
        "name": "Marzo",
        "value": 59
    },
    {
        "name": "Febrero",
        "value": 60
    },
    {
        "name": "Mayo",
        "value": 8
    }
]
```

Lo estoy filtrando por es mes que quiero por ejemplo los de marzo:

```
marzo =
[
    {
        "name": "Marzo",
        "value": 49
    },
    {
        "name": "Marzo",
        "value": 64
    },
    {
        "name": "Marzo",
        "value": 59
    }
]
```

Necesito sumar las propiedades value de este arreglo y obtener esto:

```
{
  name:"Marzo",
  value: 172
}
```

Solo logro obter la suma total de esta forma:

```
 const sumall = marzo.map(item => item.value).reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0);
```

Pero no sé como armar el objeto de la forma que necesito que es esta:

```
{
  name:"Marzo",
  value: 172
}
```

Espero me puedan guiar. Gracias de antemano

Comment: `{ name: "Marzo", value: sumall }` ?

Comment: @Fedex7501 imagino que no querra hardcodear "Marzo" sino tomarlo de las funciones

Comment: @HernánGarcia En `marzo.map` también está harcodeado. La pregunta dice que "logra obtener la suma total pero no sabe como armar el objeto". En cualquier caso la pregunta no está clara

Answer (score 0):

Es un poco verboso pero cumple su cometido y todo dentro de la misma funcion, lo bueno es que sirve para cualquier mes:

```js
meses = 
[
    {
        "name": "Marzo",
        "value": 49
    },
    {
        "name": "Marzo",
        "value": 64
    },
    {
        "name": "Marzo",
        "value": 59
    },
    {
        "name": "Febrero",
        "value": 60
    },
    {
        "name": "Febrero",
        "value": 40
    },
    {
        "name": "Mayo",
        "value": 8
    }
]

 const finalObj = (mes) => {
  return {
   //arma la clave/valor del mes
   "name": mes,
    //arma la sumatoria
   "value": meses.filter(el => el.name === mes ? el : "")
    .map(item => item.value)
    .reduce((prev, curr) => {
     return prev + curr
    }, 0)
  }
 }


 console.log(finalObj("Marzo"));
 console.log(finalObj("Febrero"));
 console.log(finalObj("Mayo"));
```